# Format individual line segments of a polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, format

Is it possible to apply different formats to different line segments of a polygon in QGIS? I am delineating forest stands within a property, and would like to change the formatting of one of the line segments of a polygon where it meets up against another polygon.

Comment: What do you mean by format? Different symbolization?

Comment: To my knowledge this cant be done. It would probably be easier to create a line or graphic at the intersection and give it the desired style.

Comment: Yes, I believe I mean symbolization. So for example, changing the outline color or outline style.

Answer (score 3):

symbolization applies to the 'top' level of geometry; that is, points are points and symbolized as such; polylines are polylines and symbolized as such; same with polygons.  So in this case you could either select those polygons that meet your condition of tangency, and treat those polygons differently in symbology, or you need to get these particular polygons to polyline format and then symbolize those polylines.

If it were me, I'd probably keep all your polygons as is; select out your polygons of tangency, and then convert those particular features to polylines and then figure out what to do from there.

This is all assuming your task is cartographic in nature, not analysis per se.